# Linq Where/Group By on XML Elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<RS>
    <R>
        <C0>14</C0>
        <C1>2013-11-29</C1>
        <C2>14:29:59</C2>
        <C3>289824328</C3>
        <C4>COMPANY NAME</C4>
        <C5>Top Customers</C5>
        <C6>14:29</C6>
    </R>
    <R>...</R>
</RS>
```

I am new to Linq and trying to get me head round how I would return a query based on the following criteria:

```
Select C4 As Customer, Sum(C0) As Total
Where C5 = "Top Customers"
Group By C4
```

I have got as far at returning the right rows based on the Where and Group, but can't fathom how I sum the C0 element. I'm using C# in VS2013:

```
XDocument xTest = XDocument.Load("ReportData.xml");

var query = from c in xTest.Descendants("R")
    where c.Element("C5").Value == "Top Customers"
    group c by c.Element("C4") into d
    select new {
        Customer = d.Key.Value,
        Total = ???
    };
```

Can anyone help with the final piece please...?

Cheers,

Roy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to describe which element you want to sum, in this case element `C0`:

```
var query = from c in elem.Descendants("R")
    where (string)c.Element("C5") == "Top Customers"
    group c by (string)c.Element("C4") into d
    select new {
        Customer = d.Key,
        Total = d.Sum(x=>(int?)x.Element("C0"))
    };
```

Some notes:

- Grouping by an `XElement` is not going to work; it will put the different elements into two groups even if they have the same value. Instead, consider grouping by the `.Value` or casting to a `string`.
- It is generally preferable to cast an `XElement` to a nullable type, rather than using the `.Value` property. If there is no matching element, the cast will still work, but `.Value` will cause a `NullReferenceException`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> With C#, however, casting is generally the better approach. If you cast the element or attribute to a nullable type, the code is simpler to write when retrieving the value of an element (or attribute) that might or might not exist.

Comment: `(int)x` should be something along the lines of `int.Parse(c.Element("C0").Value)`.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Also spotted the group by "object" not "string" issue. (int)x works just fine.

Have replaced the select {} array with an object I am using to bind to a Telerik control for a chart. Although the next challenge is not getting the .DataContext to recognise the query.